# Android Cannot Connect To Windows FTP Server. Always get timeout with same credentials that work in regular java

Tags: java, android, ftp, android-networking, apache-commons-net

I am trying to connect to my FTP that is running on my windows machine through my android app. I am not sure what is going wrong since the same code works in a regular java project.

My manifest has the permission

```java
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

A fragment runs the connection code. I have tried apache and edtftpj and both have the same problem.

Edtftpj

```java
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPConnectMode;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Random;
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment
{
    private Activity mainActivity;
    private EditText serverIPView, serverPortView;
    private EditText serverUsernameView, serverPasswordView;

    private Thread ftpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
              String serverHost = serverIPView.getText().toString();
              String serverPort = serverPortView.getText().toString();
              String username =serverUsernameView.getText().toString();
              String password = serverPasswordView.getText().toString();

            try {
                FileTransferClient client = new FileTransferClient();

                client.getAdvancedFTPSettings().setConnectMode(FTPConnectMode.PASV);

                client.setRemoteHost("192.168.1.50");
                client.setRemotePort(21);
                client.setUserName(username);
                client.setPassword(password);

                Random rand = new Random();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
                rand.nextBytes(bytes);
                client.connect();
                OutputStream out = client.uploadStream("temp");
                long begin = System.nanoTime();
                out.write(bytes);
                long end = System.nanoTime();
                out.close();
                client.deleteFile("temp");
                client.disconnect();
                double time = (double)(end - begin) / 1000000000;
                Log.i("RunFTP", String.valueOf(time) + " seconds");

            } catch (IOException | FTPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mainActivity = getActivity();

        // get user text view of inputted server IP and port
        serverIPView = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpSelectedIP);
        serverPortView = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpSelectedPort);

        // get user text views of inputted server credentials
        serverUsernameView = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpSelectedUsername);
        serverPasswordView = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpSelectedPassword);

        Button runButton = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpRunButton);

        runButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ftpThread.start();
                try {
                    ftpThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Apache Commons:

```java
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Random;
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment
{
    private Activity mainActivity;
    private EditText serverIPView, serverPortView;
    private EditText serverUsernameView, serverPasswordView;

    private Thread ftpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
              String username =serverUsernameView.getText().toString();
              String password = serverPasswordView.getText().toString();

            FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftp.connect("192.168.1.50", 21);
            ftp.login(username, password);
            System.out.print(ftp.getReplyString());

            int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

            if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                ftp.disconnect();
                System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            Random rand = new Random();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
            rand.nextBytes(bytes);

            ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftp.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            OutputStream out = ftp.storeFileStream("temp");
            long begin = System.nanoTime();
            out.write(bytes);
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            ftp.deleteFile("temp");
            ftp.logout();
            double time = (double)(end - begin) / 1000000000;
            Log.i("RunFTP", String.valueOf(time) + " seconds");

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mainActivity = getActivity();

        // get user text view of inputted server IP and port
        serverIPView = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpSelectedIP);
        serverPortView = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpSelectedPort);

        // get user text views of inputted server credentials
        serverUsernameView = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpSelectedUsername);
        serverPasswordView = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpSelectedPassword);

        Button runButton = view.findViewById(R.id.ftpRunButton);

        runButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ftpThread.start();
                try {
                    ftpThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The Error:

```java
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.50 (port 21) from /100.96.240.94 (port 34106) after 60000ms
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:191)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at com.enterprisedt.util.proxy.PlainSocket.createPlainSocket(PlainSocket.java:131)
        at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.<init>(FTPControlSocket.java:415)
        at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.connect(FTPClient.java:1056)
W/System.err:     at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.connect(FileTransferClient.java:424)
        at com.example.networkscanner.SecondFragment$1.run(SecondFragment.java:58)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

My windows FTP Server. Everything is set up, port forward is set, tried both connected to the same network and on mobile.

[image: Server is on correct IP and Port and is running]

Any ideas of what is happening? I am not sure what to do.

Comment: If you download an FTP app to your Android phone, can it connect to your FTP server?  + Where do you run your *"regular java project"*?

Comment: `String serverHost = serverIPView.getText().toString();` That is not the way to post code for help as we would not know what the user types in. Better something like `String serverHost = "192.168.3.12";` but... I now see you are not even using it. Dont confuse us!

Comment: Switch off the firewall on your pc.

Comment: Let a browser on your Android device try to connect with that ip.

Comment: `failed to connect to /192.168.1.50 (port 21) from /100.96.240.94 ` That does not look much like trying to connect from same network. Of course a mobile connection will not work with the used ip. Post a better exception log please.